# wireless button display turns on and off repeatedly

Tags: wireless

i installed 10.10 recently and immediately noticed that the wireless button display(blue indicates on and red indicates off) goes blue and red repeatedly when I'm connected to any wireless connection. Any fix available for that, by the way my laptop model is hp pavilion dv6700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that on some HP laptops, it is actually using the wireless indicator is being used to show activity as well as status. No idea how to turn it off though. Should slow down when you aren't using the internet.

Comment: This is also true on Dell systems, where Ubuntu utilizes the Wifi Status light on the system to also show activity, which in some cases can be useful.  There's no fix to this as of yet, however.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually having problems with wireless? I am pretty certain that this is normal behaviour as designed. My HP does something very similar to indicate activity.

Enjoy Das Blinkenlichts!

Comment: Well there are no problems with the connection, it's just that it was strange to see the light changing repeatedly as if i was disconnecting and connecting repeatedly.